# Can you eat turkey eggs?

Tags: eggs, turkey

I'm considering acquiring a few turkey hens and was wondering can you eat Turkey eggs? Has anyone eaten one? How do they taste?

Comment: After seeing a turkey I would not bother trying to steal eggs to it XD, chickens are small and manageable if they get angry, turkey can be a little more dangerous I guess ^^. I think eggs are eatable, if you can get them safely :)

Comment: I very recently found out they were a thing (along with also-interesting duck eggs and too-pricey-for-now goose eggs), by seeing them for sale on a local farmer's market type website.  Haven't had a chance to try them, though I intend to.  Others have better answers, so I'll leave it at this - check the Internets well, and you might be able to find some to taste (before a larger acquisition, as it were)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, you absolutely can eat turkey eggs. They are somewhat like duck eggs in that they are richer and creamier in taste. However, turkeys don't lay nearly as many eggs as chickens - perhaps 100 a year as opposed to a hen's 300, so don't expect to enjoy them too often.

Comment: But note that "a few turkey hens" each laying a hundred or so eggs a year still equates to about an egg a day.

Comment: Are they approximately the same size too?

Comment: @BrownRedHawk they are a little bigger, but the main difference is they are more pointed.

Answer (score 15):

Turkey eggs look and taste like chicken eggs, they are just bigger. The ones I have tried had a higher yolk to white ratio, and were much richer as a result. Perfectly safe to eat.

Comment: `Perfectly safe to eat.` - As in raw, like boxers [did](http://www.slate.com/articles/news_and_politics/explainer/2006/12/do_boxers_drink_raw_eggs.html)?

Answer (score 13):

Yes, and here's a rare example of some on sale in a supermarket, in the "eggs" section.

These images are taken from the [Buzzfeed article "19 Times Waitrose Went Way, Way Too Far"](http://www.buzzfeed.com/robinedds/times-waitrose-went-way-way-too-far#.gjQ9WnqRgW), which gently makes fun of a UK supermarket chain that has a reputation for being rather posh. Individual Twitter users are credited in that article.

[image]

For a size comparison, you can just make out a box of hen's eggs on the left.

For an alternative size comparison, here's the same company's brand of osterich egg(s), duck eggs and quail eggs, on similar shelving in a branch of the same supermarket:

[image]

Comment: Golly 20 pounds for a ostrich egg. I know some Karoo farmers who would salivate and the idea of getting such a price for a ostrich egg.

Answer (score 4):

Yes - they are even commercially available now. In fact, almost all bird eggs are edible. Only a few birds have any kind of poison, and they live in Indonesia. [This source](http://www.eattheweeds.com/eggs-for-survival-and-food-2/) gives more details about the two kinds of birds that are known to be toxic, and the nutritional benefits of eating eggs.

However, given the difficulty of obtaining eggs from large hens and finding the nests of smaller birds, they are not often described in survival or wildlife guides.