# Substituting different types of eggs

Tags: substitutions, eggs

I know that it is unlikely but if I do at some point live in the country and have ducks, turkeys, and geese producing eggs as well as chickens and my chickens for some reason aren't laying eggs can I use duck eggs, turkey eggs, or goose eggs in a recipe that calls for eggs but doesn't specify the kind of egg(which usually means large chicken eggs are used)? If so are there any major adjustments I would have to make besides the number of eggs used?

Comment: I've never used these sorts of eggs but I would think the **type** or recipe you're making would really determine whether these can be used or if adjustments are necessary... for example, omelets probably won't care but baking could be problematic. What sort of uses are you planning on?

Comment: Related: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/61942/can-you-eat-turkey-eggs

Comment: Although for omelets you'd just need to be concerned with the total volume, for other recipes that are less forgiving you might need to know what the volume of whites are vs. volume of yolk.

Answer (score 3):

Duck, turkey and goose eggs are larger in size. One duck egg could be the equivalent of 2 chicken eggs. I would think you would need to determine the difference by weight, once out of the shell.
The taste would not be discernable, except in an omelet or alone cooked for breakfast. The flavor would then be stronger. Hope that helps.

Comment: I also find that the consistency of the various fluids is somewhat different... Advocaat, Coquito and Eggnoggs sometimes call for differ types of yolks, and this contributes to the thickness and texture of these custard like liquers.

Comment: I've heard (I think in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1dGBRGtyzX0) from Traci Des Jardins, a pretty serious chef) that the fat content is different, so there's a difference in richness as well when cooked alone. If used in recipes besides simply cooked eggs, that extra fat could also have a noticeable effect. Do you know if that's true?

Answer (score 2):

I used 2 duck eggs in a recipe that called for 3 large (chicken) eggs and the cake came out fine. I don't mind using "other" eggs for baking, but not a fan of duck egg omelets. The taste is very different.